# How to change severity of the rule in sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

Can anyone tell me how exactly to change severity of the rule in sonar?
There is a special section in sonar for activities like this - Quality Profiles. But the opportunity of changing severity is disabled.

How to make it enabled? Maybе I need some special rights for those activities? If so, what are these rights?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

These steps apply to sonar 6.7

1. Create a new profile `my way` by copying the default.

[image]

2. Activate that profile for your sonar project

[image]

You may also want to set that profile as a default

[image]

3. Open the new profile `my way`
4. Deactivate the rule you want to change

[image]

5. Activate the rule again.

Get id in description:

[image]

Search for id in rules:

[image]

Finally you can set a new severity level
(You'll find the activation button at the button of the description)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In versions prior to 3.6, management of quality profiles is restricted to system administrators.

Since SonarQube 3.6, there is a dedicated "Administer Quality Profiles" permission.

See [Quality Profiles](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-Security) in the SonarQube documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For SonarQube 7.9

1. Select the Rules Tab
2. Select a rule
3. Click the change button
   (You can only change custom profiles)