# Configuring SonarQube Code Smell rules with Gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

Gradle and Sonarqube here.

When I run `./gradlew sonarqube` and view my analysis in the SonarQube web UI I got a bunch of different "*code smells*", some of which I agree with, and others which I do not.

I would like to configure SonarQube to report on the code smells I care about (agree with) but to ignore/exclude reporting on the ones I disagree with.

But looking in their documentation, it doesn't appear that SonarQube provides configurable rules, is that the case? If not, how do I (using Gradle) configure SonarQube's rule set for code smells?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change severity of the rule in sonar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313267/how-to-change-severity-of-the-rule-in-sonar)

Comment: Possibly, and thanks (+1)! So instead of configuring the rules in my Gradle build (`build.gradle` file), it seems to suggest I change a configuration in the SonarQube server itself?

Comment: Yes, quality profiles and rules are configured in SonarQube server itself.